# How do I use Healthkit observer queries with background delivery without prompting non-HK users for permissions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, healthkit, hkobserverquery

Users of this app can choose whether they would like to use Healthkit features (they are not necessary for the app to work). I would like to set up an observer query to send data to the server in the background.

According to Apple's documentation at this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobserverquery/executing_observer_queries

> If you plan on supporting background delivery, set up all your observer queries in your app delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. By setting up the queries in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, you ensure that the queries are instantiated and ready to use before HealthKit delivers the updates.

From my understanding, setting up your observer queries in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method means that I would have to prompt users for permissions at the first launch. Is it possible to set up background delivery from another place? For example, could I do so at the same time as I already prompt users for permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible flow is:

- In `didFinishLaunching`, check `UserDefaults` for a Boolean that indicates the user has approved HealthKit integration.  If it is `true` then call a function to set up your observer queries.
- At the point in your app execution where the user indicates that they want to provide access to HealthKit data, prompt for permission and then set the Boolean in `UserDefaults` once you have permission.
- At this point you would also call your function to set up your observer queries so that you start receiving data.